# Why is it that iteration is commonly used on binary search trees but rarely on binary trees?

Tags: recursion, iteration, binary-search-tree, binary-search

Is it because BST have attributes that are easy to iterate over, thus we don't need the extra heap of memory introduced by recursion? Why then is iteration not used on binary trees? Other than the numbers being oddly placed, is this a significant factor to omit the use of iteration?

Comment: Recursion is commonly used to traverse any kind of tree data structure. Iteration is hardly ever used.

Comment: Can you think of any reason why iteration would be preferred over recursion in BST? This question was brought up in my recent final exam and I'm just curious why this was even assumed. My answer was because BST has the predictable property that the value of any node in the left subtree will always be less, so we can apply procedures that are guaranteed to work for every node in the BST. (and vice versa for a right subtree)